# is there a way to look for all commands in CentOS

Tags: shell

Is it possible to look for all commands in CentOS? like a command lists all commands so I could use `grep` to filter what I am looking for? There are commands like `firewall-cmd` sometimes you remember key words but not the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is it possible to look for all commands in CentOS?

> lists all commands so I could use grep to filter what I am looking for?

That is what `apropos` is for.

> apropos - search the manual page names and descriptions

...

> Each manual page has a short description available within it.
>          apropos searches the descriptions for instances of keyword.
>
> keyword is usually a regular expression, as if (-r) was used, or may
>          contain wildcards (-w), or match the exact keyword (-e).  Using these
>          options, it may be necessary to quote the keyword or escape () the
>          special characters to stop the shell from interpreting them.
>
> The standard matching rules allow matches to be made against the page
>          name and word boundaries in the description.
>
> The database searched by apropos is updated by the mandb program.
>          Depending on your installation, this may be run by a periodic cron
>          job, or may need to be run manually after new manual pages have been
>          installed.

Source [apropos(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/apropos.1.html)

Examples:

> The following example demonstrates the output of the apropos command
>   with an regexp keyword (abc.n) and a regular keyword:
>
> ```
> $ apropos abc.n xzless
> XTestGrabControl (3) - XTest extension functions
> xzless (1)           - view xz or lzma compressed (text) files
> ```
>
> In this example, apropos is used to search for the keywords (with an
>   regexp .) "abc.n" and xzless, and apropos returns the indicated man
>   pages that include the keywords.

Source [apropos (Unix) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apropos_(Unix)#Sample_usage)

Comment: very handy and useful tool, wonder why it is called apropos. You mentioned manDB, I have never paid enough attention to man system. How it is stored, how it is used, now I am curious, gonna dig more

Answer (score 0):

You can use your PATH variable and list content of all folders in it

`LIST = ""

for i in $(echo $PATH | tr ":") do
  FOLDER = ls -a $i
  LIST = "$LIST $FOLDER"
done
echo $LIST`